# C# Picturebox not loading that is added in code

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a procedure which draws in the player picture box, as below:

```
public static PictureBox drawPlayer(Engine.Tile location, Image looks)
    {
        PictureBox player = new PictureBox();
        player.Location = location.img.Location;
        player.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        player.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        player.Name = "Player";
        player.Visible = true;
        player.BringToFront();

        return player;
    }
```

However, it is not working, it is called as such:

```
t.Controls.Add(drawPlayer(location, image));
```

Any help with this would be great or an answer as to why this doesn't work, I have temporarily set the colour of the box to yellow just to make it really stand out when it does *finally* decide to load.

Thanks,
Laurence

Comment: Are you every calling `Controls.Add(player);`?

Comment: Yes, I call it at the end of my procedure which draws the rest of my form.

Comment: I'll throw a few other questions around then, have you tried bringing the control to the front after it has been added? Do the controls that are added afterwards draw despite this?

Comment: Doing that worked, thank you muchly. Very odd, considering this picturebox is added after all my other controls.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `player.BringToFront();` after the control has been added into the form, as it does not exist on the form when you call this in the method that is making the PictureBox.